# How to call an asynchronous method when pressing a button using MVVM?

Tags: c#, mvvm

I have now been looking for a way to bind a command to a button that should prompt a function in my ViewModel that is async and that should start the call and be able to cancel the call. I have taken a look at Stephen Cleary's tutorials and tried to convert them to my needs though the Command manager does not exist in current context in the AsyncCommandBase and when you take a look at his git project code it is nothing like the one in his tutorial... I have no clue where to continue to get my answer so here we go. I have a ViewModel that should run a function that is async and that should run by a click of a button? Is there any way to get this done without writing a new library? I have made an interface that looks like this...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Threading.Tasks; 

    namespace Data
    {
        public interface IAsyncCommand : ICommand
        {
            Task ExcecuteAsync(Object parameter); 
        }
    }
```

and a base Commandclass that looks like this

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace Data
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An async command that implements <see cref="ICommand"/>, forwarding <see cref="ICommand.Execute(object)"/> to <see cref="IAsyncCommand.ExecuteAsync(object)"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public abstract class AsyncCommandBase : IAsyncCommand
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The local implementation of <see cref="ICommand.CanExecuteChanged"/>.
        /// </summary>
        private readonly ICanExecuteChanged _canExecuteChanged;

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates an instance with its own implementation of <see cref="ICommand.CanExecuteChanged"/>.
        /// </summary>
        protected AsyncCommandBase(Func<object, ICanExecuteChanged> canExecuteChangedFactory)
        {
            _canExecuteChanged = canExecuteChangedFactory(this);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Executes the command asynchronously.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="parameter">The parameter for the command.</param>
        public abstract Task ExecuteAsync(object parameter);

        /// <summary>
        /// The implementation of <see cref="ICommand.CanExecute(object)"/>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="parameter">The parameter for the command.</param>
        protected abstract bool CanExecute(object parameter);

        /// <summary>
        /// Raises <see cref="ICommand.CanExecuteChanged"/>.
        /// </summary>
        protected void OnCanExecuteChanged()
        {
            _canExecuteChanged.OnCanExecuteChanged();
        }

        event EventHandler ICommand.CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { _canExecuteChanged.CanExecuteChanged += value; }
            remove { _canExecuteChanged.CanExecuteChanged -= value; }
        }

        bool ICommand.CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return CanExecute(parameter);
        }

        async void ICommand.Execute(object parameter)
        {
            await ExecuteAsync(parameter);
        }
    }
}
```

the link leads to his tutorial and if you need it tell me and I'll send his git code in a hurry! :D

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/april/async-programming-patterns-for-asynchronous-mvvm-applications-commands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see why you'd need to create a async version of your `RelayCommand`. You could simply run a async method when the command executes that listens for a cancellation token. Something like:

Your command: `public ICommand DoSomethingCommand { get; set; }`

Instantiate your command somewhere: `DoSomethingCommand = new RelayCommand(DoSomething);`

And an example of the `DoSomething` method:

```
private async void DoSomething()
{
    using (var cancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource())
    {
        await Task.Run(() => 
        {
            for(i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested) break;
                //Here's where something is done.
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Bind normally: `<Button Content="Do Something" Command="{Binding DoSomethingCommand}"/>`

Just in case you need it, here's a simple `RelayCommand` you can use:

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
    {
        public RelayCommand(Action execute, Func<bool> canExecute)
        {
            CommandManager.RequerySuggested += (s, e) => CanExecuteChanged(s, e);
            CanExecuteDelegate = canExecute;
            ExecuteDelegate = execute;
        }
        public RelayCommand(Action execute) : this(execute, () => true) { }
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged = delegate { };
        public Func<bool> CanExecuteDelegate { get; set; }
        public Action ExecuteDelegate { get; set; }
        public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => CanExecuteDelegate();
        public void Execute(object parameter) => ExecuteDelegate();
    }
```

I do recommend using a proper library like MVVM Light. Hope this helps.

Comment: would this be seen as following the mvvm style?

Comment: and is there any way to use parameters for the async function to take in info from the ui?

Comment: Be rest assured, this indeed follows the MVVM pattern :). In regards to parameters, the implementation of the `RelayCommand` I mentioned before does not support parameters but you cold definetly adapt it. Even simpler, I think, would be to add the properties you want to pass as parameters to your view model and bind them to your UI. When the UI gets updated, so does the property in your view model. The methods in your view model can read those properties as they are part of the same class, so you don't specifically have to pass them as parameters to your command.

Comment: Ah thnx for the help :D